# Proof: $\underset{\|q\|=1}{\max} q^TAq = \lambda_{\max}$ with $q$ the corresponding eigenvector ($A$ symmetric)

Tags: matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-optimization, qcqp

This problem is quite old and there should be similar problems. I know the following technique:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
q^TAq=q^TU\Lambda U^Tq=(U^Tq)^T\Lambda (U^Tq)   
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}

1. Since $A$ is symmetric, $U$ must be orthogonal.
2. If picking $q=q_{\max}$ such that $Aq_{\max}=\lambda_{\max}q_{\max}$, so we have (also by the fact that $U$ is orthogonal)

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & \cdots \end{bmatrix} \Lambda  
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \end{bmatrix}=1\lambda_{\max}1=\lambda_{\max}
$$

> However, it does not really prove the title. If I can come up with $\bar{q}$ with $\|\bar{q}\|=1$, which is not the eigenvector of $A$ such that $\bar{q}A\bar{q}\geq q_{\max}Aq_{\max} $?

My work:

By contradiction,  $$\bar{q}A\bar{q}- q_{\max}Aq_{\max}\geq 0 \Rightarrow [U^T(\bar{q}- q_{\max})]^T\Lambda [U^T(\bar{q}- q_{\max})]\geq 0$$

then how to do the next step?

Comment: The implication in the last formula is incorrect.

Comment: Also, since $A$ is not necessarily positive semidefinite, you cannot conclude nonnegativity.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Why can't I do that?  I assume at first that $\bar{q}A\bar{q} \geq q_{\max}Aq_{\max}$.

Comment: $$\bar{q}^T A \bar{q} - q_{\max}^T A q_{\max} \neq (\bar{q} - q_{\max})^T A (\bar{q} - q_{\max})$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & x^T A x\\ \text{subject to} & x^T x = 1\end{array}$$

where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is symmetric and, thus, has real eigenvalues. We define the Lagrangian

$$\mathcal{L} (x,\lambda) := x^T A x - \lambda (x^T x - 1)$$

Taking the partial derivatives of $\mathcal{L}$ and finding where they vanish,

$$(A - \lambda I_n) \, x = 0_n \qquad \qquad \qquad x^T x = 1$$

Thus, we conclude that the maximum is attained at the intersection of one of the eigenspaces of $A$ with the unit Euclidean sphere.

Comment: if you don't like the Lagrangian so much : $f(x) = \frac{x^T A x}{x^T x}$, $\nabla f (x)= 2\frac{A x}{x^T x}-2\frac{x^T A x}{(x^T x)^2} x = \frac{2}{x^T x} ( A x - \lambda x)$ with $\lambda = \frac{x^T A x}{x^T x}$.  The fact that $A$ is symmetric tells us there is a maximiser $x^*$, and hence that $\nabla f(x^*) = C(Ax - \lambda x) = 0$ i.e. it is an eigenvector of $A$.